# Retention of modification dates using Ubuntu Live CD

Tags: data-recovery, live-cd

If I were to use Ubuntu Live CD to perform data recovery from a hard drive, would the recovered data retain the modification dates on files?

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to recover? Is the file system working or not in the drive you want to recover from? What file system are you copying from and what file system are you copying to?

Comment: Music, image, video, html etc. files. The data is on a working drive, but became inaccessible through normal means after I transferred it from another drive to this one. The drive is working and functional beyond this (I can save and alter files, install programs etc. on it), but all of this specific data is only accessible through hard drive recovery software (which has been found to be in good integrity with visible previews.) It shows up as occupied space under properties, but that's it. It's an NTFS drive, and I was planning on copying it to an external.

Comment: Maybe you deleted the files by mistake? How did you transfer it from another drive to this one? I mean which operating system was used, and which tool (program name)? - Anyway, it seems that modification dates are not very important for Music, image, video, html files. I can see the benefit for sorting image files by date, but not very important. - Before doing anything else, please recover the files through hard drive recovery software to a separate drive, and after that try to repair the NTFS file system, when the drive with the NTFS file system is connected to computer running Windows.

Comment: I did not delete the files by mistake, the hard drive properties show the space occupied by the exact amount of data I copied over, and I was able to view all of my files via a trial version of Seagate's recovery software. I merely cut and pasted the files from one drive (with Windows 10 64 bit home premium edition) to another (that had no OS installed on it, and was to function as a storage drive for a boot drive.) And I will do that, but again, I am wondering if Ubuntu Live CD will be able to retain modification dates on files.

Comment: If you can repair/restore the file system, such that it will see the missing files, I think the modification dates will survive. But if you use recovery tools, I don't know. Maybe, depending on what can be found (if the date information is still there, and if the recovery tools can 'see' it).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the Live CD to copy from said hard-drive to another hard-drive, and not to the CD itself, [this answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/114198/497087) shows how to use the `cp -p` command to copy a file while retaining modification times. As per that answer:

> `cp -p` does the trick. For Linux:

```
-p same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps
```